# How can I skip errors and continue running Script?

Tags: applescript

I would like to know if it is possible to ignore a shell script command
and continue running the rest of the code, for example if the following
command return me nothing in the terminal and I continue to the next command.

EDIT:
I tried: 2>/dev/null

````
    try
        do shell script "kextstat|grep -y appleintel >/tmp/Intel.txt" with administrator privileges

        on error  
        display alert "blabla..."

    end try
end showIntel:```
````

Comment: Your question is ambiguous. If you don't want your _AppleScript_ to report anything when `grep` doesn't find _appleintel_, and you want your shell command to fail silently and allow your _AppleScript_ to continue running... Consider utilizing the shells [OR operator](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html) (`||`) with `exit 0` on its right-hand side. This way your shell command always exits with a zero status code. For instance replace all `try....end try` above with: `do shell script "kextstat | grep -i appleintel >/tmp/Intel.txt || exit 0"  with administrator privileges`

Comment: @RobC, thanks its working!